# How to learn about Threads, Especially in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have always been kind of confused by threads, and my class right now makes heavy use of them. We are using java.util.concurrent but I don't even really get the basics. UpDownLatch, Futures, Executors; these words just fly over my head. Can you guys suggest any resources to help learn what I need from the ground up?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: +1 just to counter the negative attitudes :).

Comment: @Lirik: You should vote up the question because it has merit, not just because you feel sorry for the OP.

Comment: @Software Monkey: I wouldn't feel sorry for the OP if his question didn't have merit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that you already went through the [Java tutorial's threading chapter?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

There are many good books on threading in general, but also specifically in Java.

For example, [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Read ["Java Concurrency In Practice"](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) by Brian Goetz.  Great book.

Or Doug Lea's ["Concurrent Programming In Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090).  Old school, terrific stuff.  Pre-dates the concurrent package, but it's the basis for a lot of it.

Comment: CPiJ is great for learning the solid foundations of concurrent programming

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a beginners book, check out [Java Thread Programming](http://www.programix.com/threadbook/index.html) by Paul Hyde . The other books like "Java Concurrency in Practice" and "Concurent Programming in Java" can be read to get an in depth understanding of concurrency (and specially the new java.util.concurent API) but may not be good for beginners.